# MS SQL: doesn't an "INSTEAD OF INSERT" trigger get outdated?

Tags: t-sql, triggers, insert

I have some experience in Oracle PL/SQL, and I'm now learning MS SQL.
I came across the following situation:

When inserting in a table, the values to be inserted in columnA automatically had to be overwritten to MAX(columnA) + 1

In Oracle I would easily do this with a "Before insert" trigger.

In MS Sql it seems that the before should be emulated by an 'Instead of insert' trigger.

My question is: Say, I write a new Insert statement containing the max+1 for this columnA in an 'Instead of insert trigger'.

If at some later point in time a column is added to the table, my insert query in the trigger won't have this column unless someone remembers to update the trigger as well..

Is this a correct assumption?

Is there a better way of achieving this?

EDIT: assume the numbers in this column can be arbitrarily adapted.

Comment: why not an identity column, or a [sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: @tschmit007: I agree, but let's say there is other manipulation happening to that column as well. A sequence would get 'desynchronized'. An identity column cannot be edited as far as I know. I would like to keep using triggers

Comment: So did you test adding new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if you have an INSERT INSTEAD OF trigger with:

INSERT INTO table
( columnnames )
VALUES
( values )

and afterwards you add a new column to table, any insert will fail because the instead of insert does not mention all columns.

*"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."*

I assumed that this wouldn't happen if the new column allowed null values, my mistake.

Thanks to @Blam for making me doubt myself :)